# PHP how to get spesific data from an array based on id list in another array

Tags: php

I am having problems summing specific data from an array based on an ID list in another array. Let's say I have an array like this:

```
[
    [
        "student_id" => "1",
        "score" => "10",
    ],
    [
        "student_id" => "1",
        "score" => "10",
    ],
    [
        "student_id" => "2",
        "score" => "10",
    ],
    [
        "student_id" => "3",
        "score" => "10",
    ],
]
```

Then I have a list of students' IDs in the array

```
$list = [1, 2, 3];
```

- 1 = 20
- 2 = 10
- 3 = 10

What I want to achieve is to sum the score based on the student's ID, then push it to a new array `1 = 20, 2 = 10, 3 = 10`. I do this with a nested loop but it's not working. I have no idea how to do this.

Please give me a hint of how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// assuming your first array is $data.
$result = collect($data)
->whereIn('student_id', $list)
->groupBy('student_id')
->map(function ($group) {
    return $group->sum('score');
})
->toArray();

print_r($result);
```

the output will be:

```
Array
   (
      [a] => 20
      [b] => 10
      [c] => 10
   )
```

Comment: wow this way really simple and really good for the performance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of loops and conditional statements in PHP.

```
// Initialize empty array to store the sums
$sums = [];

// Iterate over the original array
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $studentID = $item["student_id"];
    $score = (int)$item["score"]; // Convert score to integer

    // Check if the student ID is in list
    if (in_array($studentID, $list)) {
        // If the student ID already exists in the sums array, add the score
        if (isset($sums[$studentID])) {
            $sums[$studentID] += $score;
        } 
        // If the student ID doesn't exist in the sums array, 
        // initialize it with the score
        else {
            $sums[$studentID] = $score;
        }
    }
}

// Print the sums
print_r($sums);
```

Comment: thanks for your referense this work really good also

Answer (score 1):

```
$scores = [];
foreach ($data as $student) {
    if (in_array($student['student_id'], $list)) {
        if (!isset($scores[$student['student_id']])) {
            $scores[$student['student_id']] = $student['score'];
        } else {
            $scores[$student['student_id']] += $student['score'];
          }
    
    }
}
print_r($scores);
```